# Backing up Bios / Dumping BIOS vars

Tags: bios

I'd like to alter some VRAM numbers on my laptop—and this has lead me to modding my BIOS via an EFI shell (because, of course, there are many options locked away from the user when it comes to something like an HP laptop).

One major problem is that, in order to figure out what variables I'd need to change, I have to look specifically at a dump of my BIOS. None of the tools I've found have been able to successfully do this. [This](http://forums.mydigitallife.info/threads/9856-Universal-BIOS-Backup-Toolkit) tool seemed the most promising, but it could not detect my BIOS.

My impression is that its output is a non-human readable file that is, effectively, a backup of everything in one's BIOS (I have a PERL script that would parse it into somewhat human-readable form; then I will find exactly what variables I need to alter).

### Side Info:

Eventually, I will enter a command into the shell similar to this:

```
setup_var 0x18c 0x10
```

Where `0x18c` is the variable that determines dedicated memory-share allocation to the video, and `0x10`refers to the 16th option, 512MB (these are for some other BIOS, very similar to mine, but I don't want to use these in case they're not the same).

I looked at [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126132/how-to-dump-bios-data-to-a-file) thread, but I don't think this is what I'm looking for. I attempted to run the script on both the `dmidecode` and `dmidecode -u` output to no avail.

Any ideas?