# How to find out why server turned on

Tags: debian, syslog

I have a PC running as debian server. Usually, the server is shut down until I press the power button or send a Magic Packet via WakeOnLan.

But sometimes, the server turns on alone.

How can I find out why the server turned on?

I already took a look at my syslog file: https://pastebin.com/FU207KDc
but coudn't find the cause.

Comment: Arch documentation to the rescue ... [Arch: Wake-on-LAN](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Wake-on-LAN#Hardware_settings)  ... "It is known that some motherboards are affected by a bug that can cause immediate or random wake-up after a shutdown whenever the BIOS WoL feature is enabled " ... [Arch Reference Thread](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=173648)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on BIOS vendor and type, but in most cases you can:

```
dmidecode | grep "Wake-up Type"
        Wake-up Type: Power Switch
```

If you don't have dmidecode command, you need to install it:

```
apt install dmidecode
```

> You can look at [**this answer**](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126132/how-to-dump-bios-data-to-a-file) to find out how to retrieve more
>   information from your BIOS.